# How to make NumberPicker text area wider?

Tags: android, numberpicker

I'm using `NumberPicker` with `String` values displayed. Here is the example:

```
odaberiRazinu.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
odaberiRazinu.setMinValue(0);
odaberiRazinu.setMaxValue(3);

odaberiRazinu.setDisplayedValues( new String[] { "FirstAnswer", "SecondAnswer", "ThirdAnswer", "FourthAnswer"} );
```

I have problems, because from FirstAnswer, only it's only visible "stAnsw" (something like that). When I move it, then it gets wider sometimes, but it's not working well.

Is there a way to make a display area wider or is there a better way to make `NumberPicker`-like mechanism for `Strings`?

EDIT (this is XML layout):

```
<NumberPicker 
        android:id="@+id/section_numberPicker"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works for me. The NumberPicker is as wide as the longest item text. Maybe you have to choose a different size for the parent layout.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <NumberPicker
        android:id="@+id/section_numberPicker"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

</FrameLayout>
```

[image]

Also you can set a static widht `android:layout_width="300dp"` but then it will truncate the text ifi it is longer.